# How to view dicom images in android?

Tags: android, image, view, dicom

I want to view .dcm file in my project so can please suggest me any library or way to view dicom files in android.

thanks.

Comment: My image viewer (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tdfsoftware.fivfree) supports a much wider range of DICOM files than the project listed below. You can invoke it through an intent to view files from your project.

Comment: how can i use your FIV?

Answer (score 2):

You can download Droid Dicom Viewer from the below url

https://code.google.com/p/droid-dicom-viewer/
It is Free and Open Source Software (FOSS) licensed under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation.

Comment: its not working properly i think so.is there is another way.;)